# jfreechart in jsp

Tags: java, jfreechart

i want to create a pie chart in jsp using jfree chart, i am using this code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page  import="java.awt.*" %>
<%@ page  import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.entity.*" %>
<%@ page  import ="org.jfree.data.general.*"%>
<%
  final DefaultPieDataset data = new DefaultPieDataset();
  data.setValue("One", new Double(43.2));
  data.setValue("Two", new Double(10.0));
  data.setValue("Three", new Double(27.5));
  data.setValue("Four", new Double(17.5));
  data.setValue("Five", new Double(11.0));
  data.setValue("Six", new Double(19.4));

  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart
  ("Pie Chart ", data, true, true, false);

 try {
 final ChartRenderingInfo info = new 
  ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());

  final File file1 = new File("../webapps/jspchart/
  web/piechart.png");
  ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(
   file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  out.println(e);
  }
%>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <IMG SRC="piechart.png" WIDTH="600" HEIGHT="400" 
   BORDER="0" USEMAP="#chart">
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that i am getting this exception "java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../webapps/jspchart/web/piechart.png (No such file or directory) "

any thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

Exception clearly says "`java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../webapps/jspchart/web/piechart.png (No such file or directory)`"

Here the **piechart.png**(`../webapps/jspchart/web/piechart.png`) or **web** directory is not exists.

Verify these info and fix it.

Fix can be:-

1. Creating a `Web` folder under `jspchart` folder OR
2. Placing a `piechart.png` file under `Web` folder

Then try to compile and run application once again.

Answer (score 1):

i got this.Actually i needed the pie chart to fetch values from a database.
The database's first column is the name and second its value.
The code is:
    Table name is chart and database is maj

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>

<<%@ page  import="java.awt.*" %>
<%@ page  import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCPieDataset" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.entity.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot;" %>

<%

                String query = "SELECT * from chart";
                JDBCPieDataset dataset = new JDBCPieDataset("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maj", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","root", "password");
                dataset.executeQuery(query);

            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("File System",dataset, true, true, false);
            //chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(222, 222, 255));
                final PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
                plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
                plot.setCircular(true);

            try {

                final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
                final File file1 = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(".") + "/piechart.png");

                ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);

            }




%>
<html>
    <body>
        Heading
        <IMG SRC="piechart.png" WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="400" style="border:4px solid orange;" USEMAP="#chart" alt="image">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this path? is the file there? (i bet not).

Copy the file under that directory and your problem will be solved.

Comment: i didnt get you..which file....sorry but i'm new to jfreechart..t think it creates a static image which we can later embed into our page

Comment: Check that the file or this path exist: /webapps/jspchart/web/piechart.png